# Ubuntu 15.10 no fuse group

Tags: fuse, sshfs, usergroups, ubuntu-15.10

I am trying to use sshfs to mount a remote file system. All the guides I can find online say I need to add myself to the fuse group but when I run

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER fuse
```

I get

> gpasswd: group 'fuse' does not exist in /etc/group

however when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install fuse
```

I get

> fuse is already the newest version.

I am using a relatively new install of Ubuntu 15.10 on 64 bit.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on my experiments, explicitly creating the `fuse` group and adding your user to it is **NOT** required to mount `ssh` file system.

To summarize, here are the steps copied from [this page](http://www.ubuntux.org/fuse-sshfs):

1. install `sshfs`

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshfs
[sudo] password for johndoe: 
Reading package lists... Done
[...]
Setting up sshfs (2.5-1ubuntu1) ...
```

2. Create local mount point

`$ mkdir /home/johndoe/sshfs-path/`

3. Mount remote folder `/remote/path` to `/home/johndoe/sshfs-path/`

`$ sshfs  remoteuser@111.222.333.444:/remote/path /home/johndoe/sshfs-path/`

4. And finally, to umount ...

`$ fusermount -u /home/johndoe/sshfs-path/`

Comment: This is right, but why is creating a fuse group not required yet most tutorials online mention it. The official Ubuntu page gives no explanation for not creating a fuse group!